# How to declare global functions in Yii

Tags: php, yii

i would like to know how to declare common functions in Yii so that we can call it from any controller, view or model file. for example i would like to declare date function globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a component, simply a class in component, and then create static methods. This approach is similar to CHtml, so I think is compliant with the framework style.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere (don't remember) i saw that common functions are in file under `config/` directory (but realy anywhere you want).
If you name your file `common-func.php` path to it would be `{webroot}/protected/config/common-func.php`
To make these global functions you need to include this file in `{webroot}/index.php`.

```
//user defined functions accessible over all pages
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/common-func.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this -

**In your components**

You need to make a file like - MyClass.php and put it inside components folder. Inside the MyClass.php you can write your functions. Like -

```
class MyClass extends CApplicationComponent {

 public function get_my_info() {

     //your code here
     //your code here

     return value;
 }
}
```

**In your main.php** (config folder) -

```
'components' => array(
        'myClass' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.components.MyClass',
        ),
```

Now this function is accessible in whole application (controller, view etc.), Directly call the function get_my_info() any where and it will return your value. Like -

```
$myInfo = Yii::app()->myClass->get_my_info();
```

Source - [How to create & call custom global function in whole application](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/727/updated-how-to-create-call-custom-global-function-in-whole-application/)